# How to handle GET requests in ASP NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm new in ASP.NET Core and I have a task where I need to create a custom middleware that should check the HTTP method and the query string to identify if a GET request has got a custom key in the query string set to true.

For GET requests with the expected query string, the middleware function adds "Hello from Custom Middleware" string to the body of the response. Than the middleware component pass the request to the next component in the request pipeline. I need to do this using a lambda expression without creating controllers, classes etc.

The query string looks like `?custom=true.`

For now I did the following. Please explain to me where I went wrong and how we can handle/use the GET requests?

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app.Use(async (context, next) =>
    {

       var customQuery = context.Request.Query["custom"];
        if (customQuery == true)
        {
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello from Custom Middleware");
            return;
        }

        await next();
    });

    app.UseRouting();
```

Comment: You have access to the `context.Request` object. Does that object contain anything relating to the verb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that it was a stupid question), but maybe someone will need my answer

```
     app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {  
            var strcustomValue = context.Request.Query["custom"];
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strcustomValue))
            {
                bool customValue = bool.Parse(strcustomValue);

                if (customValue == true)
                {
                    await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello from Custom Middleware");
                }
                else
                {
                    await next();
                }
            }
        });
```